# Convert Postgress Datetime from different zone to MySql datetime in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, timezone, multiple-columns, data-conversion

<class 'psycopg2.tz.FixedOffsetTimezone'>
to
<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>

```
Convert Postgress datetime created column to PST Mysql datetime
|                created             | TimeAdded                 |
| ---------------------------------  | ------------------------- |
| 2023-02-06 00:00:06.789162+00:00   |   2023-02-06 00:02:32.667 |

Name: created, Length: 1, dtype: datetime64[ns, psycopg2.tz.FixedOffsetTimezone(offset=0, name=None)]

Name: TimeAdded, Length: 1, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: @jezrael  Can you please help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I think you are trying to do:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'postgres_datetime': ['2022-01-01 10:00:00+05:00', '2022-02-01 10:00:00+05:00']})
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['postgres_datetime'], utc=True, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z')
df['mysql_datetime'] = df['datetime'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
df['mysql_datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['mysql_datetime'])

# Set the time zone to UTC
df['datetime'] = df['datetime'].dt.tz_convert(None)

print(df)
```

which is:

```
           postgres_datetime            datetime       mysql_datetime
0  2022-01-01 10:00:00+05:00 2022-01-01 05:00:00  2022-01-01 05:00:00
1  2022-02-01 10:00:00+05:00 2022-02-01 05:00:00  2022-02-01 05:00:00
​
```

where

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2 entries, 0 to 1
Data columns (total 3 columns):
 #   Column             Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------             --------------  -----         
 0   postgres_datetime  2 non-null      object        
 1   datetime           2 non-null      datetime64[ns]
 2   mysql_datetime     2 non-null      datetime64[ns]
dtypes: datetime64[ns](2), object(1)
memory usage: 176.0+ bytes
None
```